# Not understanding why in javascript my if statement is going to the wrong line

Tags: javascript, logic

I currently have an if statement that is checking if the target is null and if the target is not null then to check if the target is not 'select...          '. If it is not BOTH null and 'select...          ' then I want it to execute the code. When I run this code it always skips the first line of the body of the if statement and goes to the second line. I do not understand why. In this case it always goes to targetValue = getTargetValue();

```
if (target != null && !(target.lastIndexOf('select...          ', 0) === 0))
    {
        permalink.href += "&Target=" + target;
        targetValue = getTargetValue();
    }
```

I am not sure if I have a logical error or not. I am using the firefox debugger and I stepped through this code.

Comment: Maybe if you did this: if ((target != null) && ...

Comment: @Dean.DePue comparisons have higher precedence than logical operators, that's not the problem.

Comment: It is not possible in the code you wrote for the `permaline.href...` line to be skipped and the `targetValue = ...` line to be executed.  Whatever is happening in your code only _looks_ like that.  In an `if` statement either the entire body is executed or not executed.  Add an alert or `console.log` somewhere to determine the values of your expressions and to trace execution.

Comment: There's no reason why it should skip the first statement of the body. It either executes the whole body or none of it.

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is with the [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) as it searches backwards from the given index. So in your case you gave it 0 which would definitely return -1

> The lastIndexOf() method returns the last index at which a given
>   element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present. The
>   array is searched backwards, starting at fromIndex.

Try this without any argument

```
if (target != null && !(target.lastIndexOf('select...          ') === 0))
    {
        permalink.href += "&Target=" + target;
        targetValue = getTargetValue();
    }
```